# Flex form : how to change the width of form automatically according to the content

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating a flex form whose code is as follows:-
`<s:layout>`
        `<s:VerticalLayout/>`
    `</s:layout>`
    `<s:Form>`
        `<s:layout>`
            `<s:FormLayout gap="5"/>`
        `</s:layout>`
        `<s:FormItem label="First Name : ">`
            `<s:TextInput id="fn" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Last Name : ">`
            `<s:TextInput id="ln" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Email Address :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="ea"/>`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Re-enter Email Address :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="rea"/>`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Password :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="pw" displayAsPassword="true" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Re Enter Password :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="rpw" displayAsPassword="true" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Security Question">`
            `<s:DropDownList>`
                `<s:ArrayList>`
                    `<fx:String>Mother's maiden name?</fx:String>`
                    `<fx:String>Birthplace?</fx:String>`
                    `<fx:String>Pet's name?</fx:String>`
                    `<fx:String>Favourite destination</fx:String>`
                `</s:ArrayList>`
            `</s:DropDownList>`
        `</s:FormItem>`
                `<s:FormItem>`
            `<s:Button label="Submit" click="abc()" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
`</s:form>`

Now here i have a problem that is, how to increase the width of dropdownmenu so that it looks great. How to make the width change based on the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either

```
<Component width="100%" />
```

or

```
<Component left="0" right="0" />
```

It depends on your purposes,

Comment: is there any other alternate to the above code? is using the form the best way to create a row column pattern like this?

Comment: how would i bring the submit button to the center?

Comment: should i use horizontalcenter in formlist container of button or in the button's tag?

Comment: try this: <s:FormItem><s:Group width="100%">
<s:Button label="Submit" click="abc()" horizontalCenter="0" /></s:Group>
</s:FormItem>

Comment: Is there an alternate to create similar form

Comment: you can manually create containers (Group, HGroup, VGroup) an align components inside them. but i think that forms are the most efficient way to do this

Comment: how would we align the button now? how would we use colspan or rowspan like we do in html?

Comment: then move the Submit button declaration out of the <s:Form/> and align it in the parent container